# Can a Doctrine entity property name and form element name different?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am learning ZF2 + Doctrine these days. I have doubt on Entity property name and form element name.

We have some naming convention to follow in our company.
For example: 
01. ( protected $_sName ) for class properties
02. ( textName ) for text element in html

How can i map these different names to work with Doctrine Hydrators in Zend Framework 2 ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Perfect time to suggest a easier convention for newer projects (arguments: less dev time, etc...). There's no way to have FOO hydrate/extract into BAR. In theory you could set up yourself a filter with ALL POTENTIAL combinations: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/NamingStrategy/UnderscoreNamingStrategy.php but that's just outrageous and will bring more troubles than anything else.

Comment: Sounds too heavy. anyway i will try it. Thanks for your answer.